# PHP Undefined offset: 5 in line [file location] - not duplicate as the answers of the other don't answer

Tags: php, arrays, explode

So, I am getting this error, even if the code I'am doing does the job I want.
I will try to explain line by line the code.

```
$bits = array();//bits is the array that I use to hold the array that explodes each line
$explParts = array();   
$parts = NULL;//variable that holds the 6 item in array (0 index so later i use parts[5])
$articleCount = 0;//variable that holds the counter for article
foreach ($files as $dataz) { //loop that goes through all files in folder
    $handle = fopen('data/'.$dataz, 'r');//open the first file, and second after it finished the first
    while (!feof($handle)){//while not end of file {do}
    $newLine = fgets($handle);//$newLine holds the *(1,2,3) line;                   
    $bits = explode(" ", $newLine);//$bits hold the array that is created after the explosion of first line
    //print_r(array_values($bits));//uncomment this if you want to see what are the values inside bits;
    $parts = $bits[5];//$parts is the variables that holds the 6th item in the $bits array
    $explParts = explode("/", $parts); //$explParts is the array that holds the items from parts that are exploded
    $findArticle = $explParts[0];//$findArticle holds the 1st ideam in $explPart array.
    $findArticle = trim($findArticle);//trimmed the value so spaces are deleted.
    if ($findArticle == "articles") {//if what's inside $findArticle == "articles", add 1 to the counter
        $articleCount++;
    }   
  }
}
echo '<p> The number of requests from the articles directory is: '.$articleCount.'</p>'; //displays the total number of request from the articles directory                 
fclose($handle);//close $handle
```

The problem is that even thou I get the corrent number of files i get this error in the file:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php on line 38 
Call Stack: 0.0011 332600 1. {main}() /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php:0 
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php on line 38
Call Stack: 0.0011 332600 1. {main}() /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php:0
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php on line 38
Call Stack: 0.0011 332600 1. {main}() /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php:0
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php on line 38
Call Stack: 0.0011 332600 1. {main}() /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/trytask2.php:0
```

Which looks like there's a problem with the 5 that I use in $parts=$bits[5].

But it's just the index of the part that i want to take from that array.

Comment: how is your `$files` variable declared? It might be the main issue.

Comment: Obviously your `$bits` array coming out of `explode()` doesn't have 6 elements in (indexes 0->5). do a `var_dump($bits)` to see what you REALLY got.

Comment: Show me a duplicate that doesn't answer the question: How to check that an array key exists before accessing it?

Comment: @MikeB: How dare you even remotely suggest that this is not a special case! ;)

Comment: @Marc B. The array contains 9 items, so 5 it's there.

Comment: Also, you don't need to declare a var prior to it's assignement in PHP

Comment: @Mike B, everywhere I looked it says that the array doesn't have enough elements yet after the first explod the array has 10 items so is 0-9 index.

Comment: @HCJJ change that `print_r` line with `var_dump($bits)` and uncomment it. Then show us the output.

Comment: @Tivie bad habit, thanks for that.

Comment: @Tivie the outup is the same. I know var_dupm($bits) should display the values inside the array but i doesn't.. Bloody weird, and eveyone here thinks I am nuts. If some want's I can send you the archive with all the files..

Comment: @HCJJ put the files and the script in GoogleDrive or Dropbox and share the link

Comment: @HCJJ "yet after the first explod the array has 10 items so is 0-9 index" - You're exploding in a loop.. the behavior in first iteration isn't always guaranteed to be the same for the rest. Humor us.. put a `if (!isset($bits[5])) { var_dump($bits);var_dump($newLine);die;}` and you'll find your reason.

Comment: @MikeB the result Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/index.php on line 34 Call Stack: 0.0007 333384 1. {main}() /home/otoma01/public_www/p1tma/index.php:0 array(1) { [0] => string(0) "" } bool(false)

Comment: You don't see what's wrong? You're pulling in an empty line from the file and exploding on false.

Comment: Not really easy for me to spot it as I just started 2 weeks ago to study php. The .txt files have an empty line at the end of them. Is there any way for me to say if line is empty, jump to next file?

Comment: `if (empty($newLine)) continue;`

Comment: Thanks @MikeB. That helped a lot and it was a solution that I haven't found anywhere.

Comment: @HCJJ Logical errors aren't easily found through Google. Tracing and debugging your own code, line by line, is the best way to solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, made easy by everyone by commenting.

```
$bits = array();
$articleCount = 0;  
foreach ($files as $dataz) {
    $handle = fopen('data/'.$dataz, 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)){
        $newLine = fgets($handle);                  
        $bits = explode(" ", $newLine);
        if (empty($newLine)) {
            continue;
        }
        $parts = $bits[5];
        $explParts = explode("/", $parts);
        $findArticle = $explParts[0];
        $findArticle = trim($findArticle);
        if ($findArticle == "articles") {
        $articleCount++;
        }
    }
}       
echo '<p> The number of requests from the articles directory is: '.$articleCount.'</p>';                
fclose($handle);
```